# Firebase: Uniquely identify a browser session

Tags: firebase

I am building an application where in analytics data gets written to Firebase.
This is a plug in to an eCommerce site and there is no guarantee that user would login to the eCom site so identifying using user id is not an option.
Of all the connected users currently online how can I selectively push a notification to a specific user? I have done this before using Node.js/SocketIO. In socketIO world this can be achieved by socket.id which is unique for a socket object.

I am rewriting the app in Firebase , any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can identify anonymous users temporarily by randomly generating a string using `push()`. Once you've assigned every anonymous user with a random ID, you can push notifications to that user by writing data to that user's location using `set` or `push`.